# How to run a service when the screen is locked?

Tags: android

I want to recognize a shake event when the screen is locked with my Android.
I made a service to run in background but when the screen is locked, it doesn't work.

Is it possible to run a service when the screen is locked?
If not, is there a workarround :)

Comment: Unlock the phone, then shake it. :)  so your service can't detect any shake events when the phone is locked?  That would make sense, as how would you tell the difference between someone jogging, with the phone in their pocket, and wanting to shake the phone?

Comment: What doesn't work? Is your code is not excuted when the screen is locked? I would suggest to share your relevent code...

Comment: Yes, the service is not working when the screen is locked. When I unlock the phone, starts working again. The service is down when the phone is locked.

Comment: When phone is locked it is probably going to sleep. Have you tried acquiring a [WakeLock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.WakeLock.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The service is down when the phone is locked

No, the service is not "down". The CPU is powered off. When the screen goes dark, the device will normally go into a sleep mode, where nothing is running. This is perfectly normal. Moreover, it is essential for giving the user decent standby battery life.

If, for a minute or two, you want to keep the device running with the screen off, use a `WakeLock`.

Comment: is there a way to keep a `Service` running (not necessarily a one which detects sensors changes) if user explicitly locks the screen? `WakeLock` wouldn't be much help here.

Comment: @alex: Explicitly locking the screen should have no impact on a service, because the screen itself has no impact on a service. What matters is when the CPU powers down, and that's where the `WakeLock` comes in.

Comment: I see. But locking the screen influences the Activity which started/is bound to the Service. After screen lock, the Activity is being destroyed. And since `Activity.onDestroy()` is the place where services should be normally destroyed... here's the problem. How to distinguish exiting the application from just the screen being locked?

Comment: @alex: "After screen lock, the Activity is being destroyed" -- only as part of a configuration change, AFAIK. "And since Activity.onDestroy() is the place where services should be normally destroyed" -- that would indicate you didn't need a service in the first place and should simply have your logic be in the activity.

Comment: "only as part of a configuration change" - but still. And I'm not sure if I understood you correctly in the second part. If I didn't destroy the Service in `onDestroy()` I would have `ServiceConnection` leak. So is there no way to keep the service alive during screen lock? From user's POV it makes a difference if (s)he locked a screen or exited using BACK button. But system treats both cases the same (when it comes to Activity -> `onDestroy()`).

Comment: @alex: "But system treats both cases the same" -- AFAIK, the screen-lock scenario is no different than any other configuration change, such as the user rotating the screen, which you also need to handle in your app. Binding is state and therefore requires care when dealing with configuration changes. However, none of this is on-topic for the question and answer that you are commenting upon.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15611/discussion-between-alex-and-commonsware)